# React Native, Element type is invalid expected a string

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I am new to React native and I am trying to build a simple tic tac toe app. Everything worked but when I added this code the program would throw an Element type is invalid: expected a string (for-built-in components)

Here is where the problem is

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native';
import {CENTER_POINTS,AREA} from './gameConstants';
import {Cross} from './cross';


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems:"center"
    },
    player:{
        fontSize:30
    },
    line: {
        position: 'absolute',
        width: 3,
        height: 306,
        backgroundColor: '#000',
        transform: [
          {translateX: 100}
        ]
      },
      board: {
        width: 312,
        height: 312,
        borderWidth: 3,
        borderColor: '#000'
      } 
  });
export default class Board extends Component{
    
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state={
            board:[[1,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],
            result:0,
            player:1
        };
    }
    render(){
        let {player}=this.state;
        let {board}=this.state;
        let arr=[]
        let key=0;
        for(let y=0;y<3;y++){
            for(let x=0;x<3;x++){
                if(board[y][x]==1){
                   arr.push(<Cross key={key} xTranslate={CENTER_POINTS[key].x} yTranslate={CENTER_POINTS[key].y} />)
                }
                key+=1;
            }           
        }
        
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                {
                    player==1 ?(
                        <Text style={styles.player}>Player 1</Text>           
                    ):(
                        <Text style={styles.player}>Player 2</Text>
                    )
                }

                <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                    <View style={styles.board}>
                        <View style={styles.line} />
                        <View
                style={[styles.line, {
                    width: 3,
                    height: 306,
                    transform: [
                    {translateX: 200}
                    ]
                }]}
            />
            <View
              style={[styles.line, {
                width: 306,
                height: 3,
                transform: [
                  {translateY: 100}
                ]
              }]}
            />
            <View
              style={[styles.line, {
                width: 306,
                height: 3,
                transform: [
                  {translateY: 200}
                ]
              }]}
            />

            { arr }


                </View>




                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
               
    
            </View>
        )
    }

 
}
```

After I added this code it threw the error can anyone help me out?

Here is Cross

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native'

export default class Cross extends Component {
  render() {
    const { xTranslate, yTranslate, color } = this.props
    return (
      <View style={[styles.container, {
        transform: [
          {translateX: (xTranslate ? xTranslate : 10) + 35},
          {translateY: (yTranslate ? yTranslate : 10) - 12},
        ]
      }]}>
        <View style={[styles.line, {
          transform: [
            {rotate: '45deg'},
          ],
          backgroundColor: color ? color : '#000'
        }]} />
        <View style={[styles.line, {
          transform: [
            {rotate: '135deg'},
          ],
          backgroundColor: color ? color : '#000'
        }]} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: 80,
    height: 80,
  },
  line: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: 8,
    height: 105,
  },

})
```

Comment: It looks like you could skip the mapping altogether and just render `arr`.

Comment: Could you show the rest of the component, and `Cross` as well?

Comment: I edited it, same thing with just rendering arr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out when I imported Cross from'./cross' I shouldn't have used curly brackets.